# codeigniter correct way to check if libraries/helper/core files is loaded

Tags: codeigniter, configuration, declaration

i'm using codeigniter 2.

Appreciate if someone could show the correct way to check if the following files :
- library file is loaded?
- helper file is loaded?
- config file is loaded?
- model file is loaded?
- third_party file is loaded?

regards

Comment: What happens when you deliberately load it incorrectly? Do you get any CI errors? Because you should.

Comment: Don't check, just load, Codeigniter has the efficient way to determine it by itself. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630019/codeigniter-load-libraries-if-not-already-loaded/23597257#23597257

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the native PHP function class_exists() to determine if the class has been defined,
before calling it. In same regard, using method_exists() will check if class method exists.

Since helpers are collection of function, not methods, checking can be done using function_exists().

```
if (class_exists('Library')) 
{
    $this->library->myMethod();
}
```

For further info please refer to

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: This is correct way to check but if the reason for checking is to include the library then do not use this. I have made a little benchmark that proves the default Codigniter way of loading libraries is the best way. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630019/codeigniter-load-libraries-if-not-already-loaded/23597257#23597257

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to check, you just load them wherever you need to be sure to have them.

Using CI's Load library (`$this->load->[library|model|helper]`) will always load it just once. You can see this if you turn on your debug logging.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I include session library several times, the used memory raise significantly, I just tested it out. Codeigniter bug?

Comment: Look at Loader.php and search for 'Second attempt ignored' (NOTE: if you supply custom names, it will create a new instance).

Comment: You are right, Codeigniter way is the most efficient way, I did a little benchmark

Comment: This is correct answer to the question, here is a benchmark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630019/codeigniter-load-libraries-if-not-already-loaded/23597257#23597257

Answer (score 8):

this is codeigniter method to check the loaded libraries.

```
//If the library is not loaded, Codeigniter will return FALSE
if(!$this->load->is_loaded('session'))
{
     $this->load->library('session');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once loaded your instance is store on the controller, so to check if a model has been loaded :

```
if (isset($this->my_model))
```

Where `$this` is your controller.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using Codeigniter's `Loader` Class. The `Loader` aka `load` has an inbuilt method `is_loaded`. `is_loaded` method checks if a class has already been loaded or not.

If the class has not been loaded then `is_loaded` returns FALSE, otherwise it returns property name.

Example:

```
$this->load->library('table');
$this->load->is_loaded('table'); //Returns 'table'
$this->load->is_loaded('blabla_library'); //Returns FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the library is exist or not before loading, You need to follow below simple way.

Hope, It will helpful.

```
if(file_exists(DOC_ROOT."application/front/libraries/" . ucfirst($library).".php"){
$this->load->library($library);}else {
echo "No library found";}
```