# CodeIgniter - Load libraries if not already loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I'm trying to do is to load libraries **if they not already loaded** (either CI's libraries, either custom ones) on many different points of a website. So I want to do a check on this.

I have done a search on Loader library and found the is_loaded() function, so I could do this for example:

```
if ($this->load->is_loaded('form_validation') === false) {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');            
}
```

The strange thing with this (with profiler enabled) is that the memory goes up, which makes me wondering wether this is the correct way or not.

Comment: You should just use $this->load->library('library'), the check is done automatically, and the library won't be loaded if it's already

Comment: Then why the memory increases???

Comment: Don't know, but still: just use `$this->load->library()`, without any check whatsoever

Comment: Does the same thing also applies and with helpers???

Comment: Yes, and same for models, it's right in the docs (and in Loader.php, if youwant to browse the actual code)

Comment: As DamienPirsy says, checks are all done automatically. If you really wanted to check for your libraries you could always use the native php functionality `class_exists('Library')`

Comment: @Jeemusu That's not a bullet-proof method, due to the class prefixes for stock CI libraries and their extensions.

Comment: @Lykos The memory goes up because the `is_loaded()` method will directly return the library object if it is already loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if i do $this->load->library('session'); in a controller and apply the same thing in a custom library, for example, the session library will load only once, right???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Around line 914 in system/core/Loader.php, The Codeigniter perform check if the library is loaded and **it will not load it again**. However, these checks consume some memory as well. To conclude which way is the best for loading libraries, I did a little benchmark (cleaning memory after each attempt) and the conclusion here is:

> **Just load the library normally with `$this->load...` and let the Codeigniter handle it**

---

**Benchmark:**

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

After initial load of Codeigniter session class, I tested various ways loading library and/or performing check if it's not loaded already. Each of these lines were executed separately for 20x times:

---

**MEMORY CONSUMPTION TEST (Not speed!)**

```
if(!$this->load->is_loaded('session')) $this->load->library('session');
```

This consumed **48.256 bytes**

---

```
if(!class_exists('ci_session')) $this->load->library('session');
```

This consumed **39.824bytes**

---

```
if(!isset($this->session)) $this->load->library('session');
```

This consumed **31.904bytes**

---

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

This consumed **21.790bytes**

---

After repeating the test for one more time, the results were the same, so I guess it might just be relevant! Please comment if I'm wrong!

---

07.08.2014. UPDATE using Codeigniter 2.2.0:
The test was repeated using 1000 iterations (not 20 like before). The results remain the same. Memory consumption was as follows: 2128b, 1856b, 1688b, 1456b

@Tim Dev notes in the comment that this benchmark doesn't necessary shows the fastest code but only lowest memory consumption code.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough and helpful reply!

Comment: I had the same problem and realised I should share this with others

Comment: Just benchmarked this by reloading a a method 100 times which tries to load the same library. `!class_exists()` 1.95 milliseconds, `!isset()` 5.6milliseconds, `!is_loaded()` 39 milliseconds,  and no checks but just trust on codeigniter checks is 300+milliseconds.  So `class_exists` is faster.

Comment: As I've made now a 1000 iterations test I've realized that we are not at the same lane here. I'm talking about memory consumption while you were bench marking elapsed time. This could have been discussed further on how these tests should be executed. The elapsed time results are though logical as Codeigniter code would have much more lines to execute than native class_exists(). If you ask me, I think reducing memory consuption would be much better practice then saving a few hundred milliseconds of time, but it's just my opionion

Comment: @intsoumen No waaaay? Too bad that this is a memory consumption test, not the speed performance test